# Selecting Multiple Text Objects

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

Consider there are two text field objects:

```
TextField1="texta";
TextField2="textb";
```

Output:

```
texta textb
```

Now I want to select from "ta" in TextField1 to "tex" in TextField2. By the drag of a mouse.

I know that by conventional methods it is not possible? Is there any other way to achieve this? And I need to highlight the text also. Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

On mouse down in one test field add a mouse over handler for the other text field.

In that handler work out from the local x co-ordinates of the mouse and the FontMetrics of the text, how many characters should be highlighted.

You can then do setSelection(...) to highlight the correct characters.

There are much easier ways of doing this if you weren't using multiple TextFields...